# Rails/RSpec: Memoized/cached block on a context level e.g. before(:context) referencing a let

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

While writing specs, I often have a expensive operation I'd like to test multiple aspects of without needing to call it each time. How do I do this, while still referencing a greater scoped variable?

```
describe Hq::UsersController
  let(:create_params) {
    {'name': 'Bob',
    'email': 'bob@burgers.com'}
  }

  describe "#create" do
    context "when a user does not already exist" do
      before(:context) do
        # (some expensive operation here)
        VCR.use_cassette('external_user_check') do
          # note: this will error out, see message below
          post :create, :params => create_params
        end
      end

      it "creates the user and dependent objects" do
        expect(User.count).to be(1)
        user = User.first
        expect(user.name).to eq(create_params['name'])
      end

      it "returns an 204 (no content) status" do
        expect(response).to have_http_status(:no_content)
      end
    end

    context "when a user already exists" do
      before(:context) do
        User.create(email: create_params['email'])
      end

      it "raises a RecordInvalid error and does not create any objects" do
        VCR.use_cassette('external_user_check') do
          expect { post :create, :params => create_params }.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
        end
        # I wish I could break this into two `it` blocks :(
        expect(User.count).to be(0)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
`let` and `subject` declarations are not intended to be called
 in a `before(:context)` hook, as they exist to define state that
 is reset between each example, while `before(:context)` exists to
 define state that is shared across examples in an example group.
```

I understand the intent of warning, but in my case, how can we run or cache an expensive operation just one time, while also reusing some shared state across contexts? Generally when I write specs, I assume the *state is the same within a context*.

Right now, it seems my only solution is to copy and paste the params in multiple `context` blocks for this to be correct. However, that would costly to maintain if the params change or if the params are lengthy.

I'm open to refactoring suggestions or if this happens to indicative of some spec code smell. Thanks!

Comment: You can try creating a before(:context) block at the error recommends, and in there set an _instance variable_ to the cached value. Reference this shared instance variable within the context's examples.

Comment: As described in the [RSpec docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let#use-let!-to-define-a-memoized-helper-method-that-is-called-in-a-before-hook) "use let! to define a memoized helper methods that is called in a before hook"